# Get NPM variable inside Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-cli

**Question:**

If I'm passing:

```
npm run build -- brl
```

How do I (or is it possible to) get the brl value inside Angular main TS file?

For e.g. Let's assume that I want to replace [npm_variable] inside my main.ts and code is below:

```js
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './[npm_variable]/app/app.module';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**Overview:**

I know Angular CLI now supports multiple app entry points with following:

```
ng build --prod --aot --app myAppName
```

I'm creating a multi-site application where I want code base to be same with multiple entry points.

I use following folder structure in order to achieve multi-site architecture. As you can see, I've common folder where all common components, config, modules, services resides. Along with it, I've different sites such as brl, chn and so on.. (around 13 different sites which share same code base)

[image: Angular Folder Structure]

Following is my .angular-cli.json

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "angular"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "brl",
      "root": "resources/angular/sites/brl",
      "outDir": "public/dist/brl",
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "../../polyfills.ts",
      "test": "../../test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "../../tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "../../tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../../styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "../../environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "../../environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "../../environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "chn",
      "root": "resources/angular/sites/chn",
      "outDir": "public/dist/chn",
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "../../polyfills.ts",
      "test": "../../test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "../../tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "../../tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../../styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "../../environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "../../environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "../../environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    },
    "lint": [
        {
        "project": "resources/angular/tsconfig.app.json"
        },
        {
        "project": "resources/angular/tsconfig.spec.json"
        }
    ],
    "test": {
        "karma": {
        "config": "./karma.conf.js"
        }
    },
    "defaults": {
        "styleExt": "scss",
        "component": {}
  }
}
```

And then I hit following command:

```
ng build --prod --aot --app brl
```

OR

```
ng build --prod --aot --app chn
```

This works well, until I realise, I need more sophisticated and Object Oriented approach. For. e.g. here, only my app.component.ts would have different code based on sites.

However, my main.ts (which is entry point of my application) is getting duplicated for all sites.

Comment: The question is specific to Angular CLI, not to Angular. At this point I would suggest to [eject](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject) the config and proceed with Webpack with the level of flexibility you need. You can process CLI args as anywhere else in Node and exposing env variables to client side scripts is a usual thing in Webpack.

Comment: @estus This helps. I updated my questions again it is not only related to angular CLI, let's assume that, I ejected and exposed webpack.config.js to my application and now I want to process CLI args inside my main.ts file as updated in question, is it possible?

Comment: I would suggest to learn from existing Angular+Webpack starter kits, e.g. https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter . It shows how the variables can be exposed exposed to client side. You can provide the value from CLI as either environment variable or parse it from args from `process.argv` or a package like `yargs`.